# How to select multiple series from a certain timestamp in SQLite Query

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite database containing event log records with a timestamp and the event details. Some of these events are alarms generated by the system. What I need to do can be best explained in the following pseudo code:

```
for each event where type="alarm" get preceeding events between event.timestamp - 1 hour and event.timestamp
```

What I do now is query the database once to find the timestamp of each alarm and then loop over the result to get all the time periods for each alarm. This creates a list of transactions that I want to use for association rule mining but I feel that leaving SQL to then come back to it in a loop is inefficient. I've searched for answers to this question but I think I can't find the right keywords to search for.

I've edited the question as it wasn't as clear as I myself thought

Comment: What is n ? What do you mean by "next" rows --- with respect to which ordering ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a self-join?

```
SELECT {column list}
from events e1, events e2
where e1.type="alarm"
and e2.time between (date(e1.time),'-1 hour') and e1.time
```